# How to prevent holes when double wrapping food?

Tags: halacha, food, kashrut-kosher

When cooking milk in a meat oven (or kosher food in a treif one) I often find that when one wraps using aluminum foil, small holes appear (probably from the heat). I was wondering if anyone knows a better way to double-wrap food?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the [heavy duty aluminum foil](http://www.ehow.com/info_8714366_difference-foil-regular-aluminum-foil.html)? It is much thicker and may solve your problem. It may take a little longer for the food to heat up, however.

Also, check out this [Q&A from Reynolds](http://www.reynoldspkg.com/reynoldskitchens/en/faq_detail.asp?info_page_id=743&):

> **Why does aluminum foil sometimes melt and leave black specks on the food?**
>
> Occasionally when aluminum foil comes in contact with a different metal or a food that is highly salted or acidic, small pinholes are formed in the foil. This is a harmless reaction that does not affect the safety of the food. It is difficult to predict, but may occur under the following conditions:
>
> 1. When aluminum and a dissimilar metal are in contact in the presence of moisture, an electrolytic reaction may occur causing a breakdown of the aluminum. To avoid this use aluminum, glass, ceramic, plastic or paper containers. Do not cover sterling silver, silverplate, stainless steel or iron utensils with aluminum foil.
> 2. A similar reaction may occur when salt, vinegar, highly acidic foods or highly spiced foods come in contact with aluminum foil. The result of these reactions is a harmless aluminum salt. Some aluminum salts are used in medicines to treat stomach disorders. The food can be safely eaten; however, the aluminum salt particles can be removed from the food to improve the appearance of the food.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/lasagna_cell

Comment: @tomsmith: Did you chose this answer as the correct answer because it worked, or because it was the only answer? Please let me know if it solved your problem?